# Why does changing Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture throw an error with one date and not other valid date

Tags: vb.net

If I used 02/16/16, I get an error. But if I use 02/07/16 it works fine.

**Error**

```
C:\temp\.Net Exam Guide 2003\Exercises\Ch11\CDContent\Exercise 11-1>ChangeCultur
e.exe
Tuesday, February 16, 2016

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "02/16/
16" to type 'Date' is not valid.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(String Value)
   at Module1.Main()
```

**Code**
    Imports System
    Imports System.Globalization
    Imports System.Threading

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim DateString As String = "02/07/16"
        Dim TestDate As DateTime = DateString
        Console.WriteLine(TestDate.ToLongDateString)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        TestDate = DateString
        Console.WriteLine(TestDate.ToLongDateString)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Expected Results**

```
C:\temp\.Net Exam Guide 2003\Exercises\Ch11\CDContent\Exercise 11-1>ChangeCultur
e.exe
Sunday, February 07, 2016
02 July 2016
```

Comment: This code will not compile under option strict: `Dim TestDate As DateTime = DateString`  you are assigning a date to a string without converting/parsing.  If the culture is GB, they dont have 16 months (even though they have a Queen)

Comment: ^^ *assigning a string to a datetime var...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to delete the following line that occurs after changing culture to en-GB

```
TestDate = TestString
```